# Executing Assembly running as 32 or 64

Tags: assembly

Is there a way to tell if the executing assembly is running in 32bit or 64bit?  I understand how to tell if it's compilied as ILOnly, x86, etc and if the OS is running 32 or 64. I could still have a dll as AnyCPU on a 64bit OS still running as 32bit because of the host app is running in 32 bit.  So, is there a way the dll can tell if it's running 32 or 64?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [Environment.Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx) in .NET 4.

In .NET 3.5 and earlier, the easiest method is to check the size of an IntPtr:

```
bool is64Bit = IntPtr.Size == 8;
```

If either of the above is false, the program is running as a 32bit Executable.